# How to remove headers from row count in batch

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, count, subtraction

I have a csv file that always contains a header row. I have been using the code below in batch to perform a count of records within the csv, which includes the header.

seems like a basic question but how do I subtract '1' from the variable %number%?

```
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" *.csv | find /C ":""
for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set number=%%a
echo %number%
```

I've tried: number = %%a-1 but that doesn't subtract, it appends '-1' to the value of number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bookmark [SS64 on CMD](https://ss64.com/nt/), and then look up [the `SET` command there](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html). You'll find that you want `SET /A number=a-1`.

Comment: perfect! i changed the above to:    set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" *.csv | find /C ":""
for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set /A number=%%a-1
echo %number%   and it worked as intended